# Reality or unreality-if you had seen the notices next day in all the papers, you must have supposed my evening's entertainment an unqualified success

Tags: grammar, conditionals, sentence-meaning

[(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter VI, published 1892)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_6)

Passage 96

> Pinkerton was in the waiting-room, feverishly jotting in his pocket-book. As he saw me enter, he sprang up, and I declare the tears were trickling on his cheeks.
>
> "My dear boy," he cried, "I can never forgive myself, and you can never forgive me. Never mind: I did it for the best. And how nobly you clung on! I dreaded we should have had to return the money at the doors."
>
> "It would have been more honest if we had," said I.
>
> The pressmen followed me, Harry Miller in the front ranks; and I was amazed to find them, on the whole, a pleasant set of lads, probably more sinned against than sinning, and even Harry Miller apparently a gentleman. I had in oysters and champagne—for the receipts were excellent—and being in a high state of nervous tension, kept the table in a roar. Indeed, I was never in my life so well inspired as when I described my vigil over Harry Miller's literature or the series of my emotions as I faced the audience. The lads vowed I was the soul of good company and the prince of lecturers; and—so wonderful an institution is the popular press—**if you had seen the notices next day in all the papers, you must have supposed my evening's entertainment an unqualified success**.
>
> . . .

Does the sentence *if you had seen the notices next day in all the papers, you must have supposed my evening's entertainment an unqualified success* express reality or unreality? It is a conditional sentence for a past situation, but in *must have supposed* the modal verb *must* isn't 'shifted' or 'moved back' in time like *will* -> *would (have supposed)*. Now, what does this sentence express - reality or unreality? Is it true what the sentence says or is it just imagined?

Edit:

To add more details: In this sentence there is the modal verb *must*. The modal verb *must* doesn't refer to the past and *must* isn't a distancing form; or, to put it differently, *must* doesn't have forms like *would* (used as a distancing form of *will*) or like *might* (used as a distancing form of *may*). However, when a speaker wants to state an unreality or a merely imagined action or occurrence, when a speaker states a counterfactual conditional sentence it (s/he ?) needs a distancing form of the modal verb in the main clause as in the sentence

*If you had not passed the test, you **would** have failed the course.*

In our sentence . . .

*If you had seen the notices next day in all the papers, you must have supposed my evening's entertainment an unqualified success*

. . . **there isn't any modal verb form equivalent to *would*** (*must* doesn't have one; we use *would have to* instead). That's why I suppose our sentence is expressing a reality: The speaker is stating that the result is a consequence of some really possible prior action or state (in this case *future in the past* of course). We also use *must + have + ...ed form* to talk about deductions and conclusions in the past. Even though there is the verb *suppose* in the main clause *'you must have **supposed** my evening's entertainment an unqualified success'*, the speaker is stating that *supposing* his success is a reality and not merely imagined, the speaker asserts or claims that you must have *supposed* this. That is to say the main clause, hence the whole conditional sentence is talking about a **real** and not merely imagined deduction or conclusion, about a **fact/factum** in the past depending on whether you had seen the notices in the papers or not. Am I right or am I wrong? That's my question.

Comment: The backshift of *must* is *must*.

Comment: Yes, but what is the meaning of this sentence - is it reality or unreality, true or just imagined? It's a conditional sentence not reported speech actually (the backshifting-tag was wrong).

Comment: Firstly, it's a value judgement ... 'I' can't _guarantee_ that anyone seeing the reviews would have _supposed 'my' evening's entertainment an unqualified success._  But conditionals always involve an event that may or may not happen / have happened, so I don't understand the question. // On another level, isn't all this fiction in any case?

Comment: "But conditionals always involve an event that may or may not happen / have happened" - a counterexample:
*If my father had a day off, we always went to see my grandfather.*

Comment: @philphil: but sometimes his father didn't have a day off, so on any given day, he may or may not have gone to see his grandfather.

Comment: What would do you think "reality" and "unreality" would mean here?

Comment: @philphil That use of "if" is not really a conditional, it's an alternate way of saying "When my father had a day off".

Comment: Are you asking about the meaning, or the grammar?

Comment: I can't help thinking that something like "you would have had no option other than to suppose...", "you would have been forced to suppose...", or "there is no doubt you would have supposed..." would be more usual these days, and "you could not but suppose" might be commoner in the 19th century.

Comment: To suppose is to believe or imagine something to be true - Not being true yet other than in the mind. Call that unreal if it matters.

Comment: I've edited the question. Why do you moderators write *Edit question* again?

Comment: @ TimR - Thank you very much indeed. Yes, I take it the same way. The speaker claims supposing his success to be a general truth - "there's no doubt about it", that's what the speaker (Loudon Dodd) wants to say.

Comment: Dear moderators, why is this question still titled **[closed]** when everybody can write a comment here? There is also the remark *Edit question* even though it has been edited already.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a conditional in this context, because "you" is not referring specifically to the audience, but refers to people in general. Another, more modern way of phrasing it would be

> anyone who had seen the notices the next day in all the papers must have supposed...

There is something "unreal" about this, though, since the people seeing the notices and coming to the stated conclusion are hypothetical.

Comment: I think it would have to be something stronger than "would have supposed" since it says "must" in the original.

Comment: Just a copying error

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted — another instance of the runaway downvoters. So I've upvoted to counter it.